# How to use heavy python script in nodejs?

Tags: python, node.js

I'm working on project about web & image processing in real time.
and these days I have some trouble merging image processing algorithm and web.

recently, I tried using python-shell.
but python script for image processing is so heavy, there are lots of function declare..
so when I tried it, error has occured.
like this
    <--- Last few GCs --->

```
[26628:00000246E4B7BC90]    28489 ms: Mark-sweep 15.8 (27.0) -> 9.5 (11.7) MB, 95.8 / 3.7 ms      (+ 75.9 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 75.9 ms, walltime since start of marking 3000 ms) (average mu = 0.994, current mu = 0.994) finalize in[26628:00000246E4B7BC90]    30344 ms: Mark-sweep 9.7 (11.7) -> 9.6 (12.0) MB, 3.1 / 0.1 ms  (+ 1.4 ms in 5 steps 

since start of marking, biggest step 0.9 ms, walltime since start of marking 1105 ms)     (average mu = 0.994, current mu = 0.998) finalize increm



<--- JS stacktrace --->



==== JS stack trace =========================================



0: ExitFrame [pc: 00007FF655BC770D]

1: InternalFrame [pc: 00007FF655B4C544]

Security context: 0x0157f57808d1 <JSObject>

2: shift [000003370F62E9F1] [internal/fixed_queue.js:110] [bytecode=000001C9A83BC239     offset=13](this=0x00b7ff3d5d69 <FixedQueue map = 0000037BE1F2C589>)

3: processTicksAndRejections [000000B7FF3C2121] [internal/process/task_queues.js:72]     [bytecode=000001C9A83BBF19 offset=17](this=0x03a32b9bfb01 <process m...



FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory

 1: 00007FF654FB46CF napi_wrap+113583

 2: 00007FF654F5F7C6 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+66646

 3: 00007FF654F605C6 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+70230

 4: 00007FF6557742AE v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94

 5: 00007FF65575C381 v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+833

 6: 00007FF65526C220 v8::internal::Zone::NewExpand+192

  7: 00007FF6559FD29E v8::internal::compiler::TypeCache::CreateRange+5742

  8: 00007FF65595F5BA v8::internal::compiler::JSHeapBroker::InitializeRefsMap+826

  9: 00007FF65595EC10      v8::internal::compiler::JSHeapBroker::InitializeAndStartSerializing+12810: 00007FF6559E72EE      v8::internal::compiler::CodeAssembler::zone+3454

 11: 00007FF6559EFB9D v8::internal::compiler::Pipeline::AllocateRegistersForTesting+4349     

 12: 00007FF6559F5410 v8::internal::compiler::TopLevelLiveRange::MayRequireSpillRange+5456

 13: 00007FF6556D1001 v8::internal::Compiler::PostInstantiation+1265

 14: 00007FF6556CE5F4 v8::internal::Compiler::GetOptimizedCodeForOSR+644

 15: 00007FF6556CE256 v8::internal::Compiler::GetFunctionFromValidatedString+1638

 16: 00007FF6556CB517 v8::internal::Compiler::CompileOptimized+87

 17: 00007FF6553C4FCA      v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+104234

 18: 00007FF655BC770D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+546637

 19: 00007FF655B4C544 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42372

 20: 00007FF655B4C6BC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748

 21: 00007FF655B4C6BC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748

 22: 00007FF655B49BF1 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+31793

 23: 00007FF655B497DC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+30748

 24: 00007FF655681F83 v8::internal::Execution::CallWasm+1395

 25: 00007FF655681906 v8::internal::Execution::Call+182

 26: 00007FF65575298D v8::Function::Call+605

 27: 00007FF654FD5265 node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope+949

 28: 00007FF654FD5530 node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope+1664

 29: 00007FF654FCEBEB v8::internal::compiler::Operator::EffectOutputCount+235

 30: 00007FF654E8F390 RSA_meth_get_flags+19728

 31: 00007FF654E8FBCE RSA_meth_get_flags+21838

 32: 00007FF654E8AAE5 RSA_meth_get_flags+1125

 33: 00007FF654FF6732 uv_thread_self+2946

 34: 00007FF654FF950F uv_pipe_pending_type+3391

 35: 00007FF655003C3C uv_loop_init+860

 36: 00007FF655003F64 uv_run+244

 37: 00007FF654F163A1 v8::internal::AsmJsScanner::GetIdentifierString+31777

 38: 00007FF654F890D3 node::Start+275

 39: 00007FF654DF6A9C RC4_options+340380

 40: 00007FF655C7F7F8 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+1300536

 41: 00007FF9F7447BD4 BaseThreadInitThunk+20

 42: 00007FF9F794CE51 RtlUserThreadStart+33
```

when I run my code, that error occurs.

and sometimes compiler ignore some code.

/////////////////////////////here is my code.//////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
socket.on('send', function(blob){


    var base64data= blob.toString('base64')

    let shell = new global.pyshell.PythonShell("example.py",options,function(err){
        if(err) console.log('err msg:', err);
        console.log('finishied');
    }
    )

    shell.on("message", rebase64 => {
      console.log("entered");
      var err = null;
      var result = Buffer.from(rebase64, "base64");
      fs.writeFileSync("result.jpeg",result);
    });




    shell.end(err=>{
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I have no idea about this situation..

Is there any way declare the function previously??

thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I will use communication between python server and nodejs using websocket or zerorpc or other methods.